# How can I wrap an image within anchor tag for like and dislike functionality

Tags: javascript, html, image, anchor

I need to wrap a heart-shaped image within the anchor tag for like and dislike function. I did but the corresponding image is behaving like an anchor tag. when I click on the image I am navigating to a particular link which I mention.
What I want is when I click on the image I just want to invoke a function for like and dislike.

[image: for your reference you can check image what i want]

```
<a>
  <div className="hidden">
    <div className="hx-243px bg-cover transitionAll-0p3 slide-item-img no-selectable" style={{backgroundImage: `url(${thumb})`}}> 
      <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgATURjH/98kkVJUXIjYg3griojiRcEN6sEFQuYlnYMeSjxYRRBPntzSg3oSRPBgQ==" style={{float: "right", padding: "5px", display: "inline-block"}}></img>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Vicky, do you have some code we can help you with?

Comment: Hello Emiel,
please check the code

```<a>
            <div className="hidden">
              <div className="hx-243px bg-cover transitionAll-0p3 slide-item-img no-selectable" style={{backgroundImage: `url(${thumb})`}}>
                <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgATURjH/98kkVJUXIjYg3griojiRcEN6sEFQuYlnYMeSjxYRRBPntzSg3oSRPBgQ==" style={{float:"right", padding:"5px", display: "inline-block"}}></img>
              </div>
            </div>
          </a>```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add event listener on anchor tag click, and then prevent default event.

Check these links:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

TL;DR

Code would be something like that

```
<a href="javascript:;" id="like">
  <img src="heart.png"/ alt="like">
</a>

<script>
  var likeButton = document.getElementById('like');

  likeButton.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // actual like implementation
  });
</script>
```

Comment: It is a simple possible example showing how to use `addEventListener` and `event.preventDefault()`. You need more complex logic to make such functionality you want